Do spell-like abilities have descriptors?
Following this thread:
What rules say that summoning undead is evil, and what rules say why?
It talks about spells and ask the question if casting a spell with an evil descriptor is an evil act or not.
As far as I know, in pathfinder, Spell-like abilities are spells until they aren't. Clerics cannot summon Evil creatures if they are Good and vice versa.
But do spell-like abilities follow the same ruling? I do not see anything saying that spell-like abilities have descriptors.
So for example:

Can an Inquisitor Monster Tactician of Evil alignment summon a good creature with his Summon Monster spell-like ability?
Would it be considered as an act of good?


Yes, spell-like abilities retain the descriptors of the spell they are “like.”

Spell-like abilities are magical and work just like spells (though they are not spells and so have no verbal, somatic, focus, or material components). They go away in an antimagic field and are subject to spell resistance if the spell the ability is based on would be subject to spell resistance.
A spell-like ability usually has a limit on how often it can be used. A constant spell-like ability or one that can be used at will has no use limit. Reactivating a constant spell-like ability is a swift action. Using all other spell-like abilities is a standard action unless noted otherwise, and doing so provokes attacks of opportunity. […] Spell-like abilities cannot be used to counterspell, nor can they be counterspelled.

(Spell-like Abilities)
The only listed differences between spell-like abilities and spells are:

They are not “spells” per se (which is relevant for things like feats, magic items, class features, and so on that say “spell” and not “spell-like ability”).

They do not have verbal, somatic, focus, or material components.

The limitations on how they can be used are indicated by the ability in question, rather than being fueled by a shared pool of spell slots.

Their casting time is either a swift action (if it is a constant effect that you are merely reactivating) or a standard action (otherwise).

They cannot counterspell or be counterspelled.


Aside from these five points, a given spell-like ability is the same as the spell it is “like” in all respects—including descriptors. Quite simply, there is no support for removing them.

It is perhaps circumstantial evidence, but it’s worth noting that Pathfinder spell-like abilities are almost word-for-word identical to D&D 3.5e spell-like abilities, and D&D 3.5e explicitly printed numerous spell-like abilities—most notably those which were “invocations” for the dragonfire adept and/or warlock classes—with their descriptors.
